# Javascript: on/off switch

Tags: switch-statement

What is wrong whith this code? I have tested it many  times but something still doesn't work.

```
var playernow = 1; //Whose player's turn it is (1 or 2)

function bobenli(playernow){
var wert="";
switch (playernow){
    case "1":
        wert="X";
        playernow=2;

    case "2":
        wert="O";
        playernow=1;
}
alert(playernow);
}
```

Comment: What is not working, what do you expect it to produce? These are things that could be good to add you your question.

Comment: I expect that playernow is canging with every request and wert is rotatory "X" and "O".

Answer (score 3):

No break statement, both cases get executed. Also as others have said you are comparing ints to strings. You can drop the quotes in the cases.

```
var playernow = 1; //Welcher Spieler dran ist )(1 oder 2)

function bobenli(playernow){
var wert="";
switch (playernow){
    case 1:
        wert="X";
        playernow=2;
        break;
    case 2:
        wert="O";
       playernow=1; 
       break;
}
alert(playernow);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     var playernow = 1; //Welcher Spieler dran ist )(1 oder 2)

function bobenli(playernow){
var wert="";
switch (playernow){
    case "1":
        wert="X";
        playernow=2;
        break;
    case "2":
        wert="O";
        playernow=1;
        break;
}
alert(playernow);
}
```

you missed break statement in following switch case... http://jsfiddle.net/yjusC/

Answer (score 0):

You need a break at the end of each case:

```
switch (playernow){
    case "1":
        wert="X";
        playernow=2;
        break;

    case "2":
        wert="O";
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

First: no break, second: you're comparing different types (int and string). This might have no impact now, but you should be careful in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
case "1": // This is looking for a string. You set playernow equal to an integer value above.
```